# Changing Price Error Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server

Good day,

I need to increase the price by 8% on certain products, but i keep getting the error below.

Any help would be appreciated

```
update Part_Sales_Price
set Sales_Price = ' ROUND (sales_price * 1.08,2) '
where Part_Number = '00001A'
```

> ```
> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
> ```

Comment: Remove the `'` from the `set Sales_Price = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes near round as below:

```
update Part_Sales_Price set Sales_Price = ROUND (sales_price * 1.08,2) where Part_Number = '00001A'
```